# Is there a way to force Qristal SDK to use available NVIDIA GPUs by default?

Tags: quantum-computing, qristal-sdk

I've been using the 1.0 release of the Qristal SDK via the Docker image, and have successfully run some circuits. I'm not sure if it is using the available GPUs however, and I'm not sure how to check this. Can I force it at runtime, or control in the running session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system has one or more NVIDIA GPUs, install the [NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and add the switch `--gpus all` to the docker run command in order to use them.

So this would look like:

> docker run --rm -it --name --gpus all qbsdk -d -p 8889:8889 registry.gitlab.com/qbau/software-and-apps/public/qbsdk

Referencing the [updated the quickstart](https://gitlab.com/qbau/software-and-apps/public/QBSDK) guide. Good catch.

Comment: It was the documentation version that fixed it for me. Thank you. I'll follow along the docs and the quickstarts now.

Comment: The guides and code all seem to be moved to GitHub now while the Docker is still on GitLab.